# Python script with BS4 not working after I made some change; syntax problem?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, syntax

I ran the code fine, then I tweaked the code and saved and closed it, tried to run it again and got a syntax error. My stupid self didn't backup the original code and now anything I change doesn't seem to fix it. I checked the source code of the website and that hasn't changed. It's erroring before even checking the website. Any suggestions on what I overlooked?

```
import requests
import time
import bs4
import sys

sys.stdout = open("links2.txt", "a")

for x in range(0, 100000):
    try:
        URL = f'https://wesbite.com/{x}'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        time.sleep(1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        website = "https://v.website.com/"

        for links in soup.find('div',id='view').find_all('a'):
            parts = links['href'].split("/")
            new_link = parts[1].replace(parts[1], website) + '/'.join(parts[2:]) + ".mp4"
            print(new_link)
    except:
        continue
```

It's reporting a syntax error on the line that reads: URL = f'https://wesbite.com/{x}'

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working code now:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

sys.stdout = open("links2.txt", "a")

for x in range(0, 100000):
    try:
        URL = f'https://wesbite.com/{x}'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        time.sleep(1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        website = "https://v.website.com/"

        for links in soup.find('div',id='view').find_all('a'):
            parts = links['href'].split("/")
            new_link = parts[1].replace(parts[1], website) + '/'.join(parts[2:]) + ".mp4"
            print(new_link)
    except:
        continue
```

It was:

```
import bs4
```

Now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Thank you! Took me more time than I would like to admit trying to figure this out. Can't believe it wasn't even the main code that I broke hah. thank you though